# making google maps go back to default location

Tags: php, google-maps, wordpress

I'm using this WP plugin (Pazzey's Store Locator) which I modified quite a bit for my purposes. So far so good, however, I'm going crazy with this: if I try a store search that returns NO RESULTS FOUND, then the map centers itself in the middle of the Pacific Ocean. I have no idea why and can't find the solution. Just to be clear: it works perfectly on load, it works perfectly on results found, this just happens when no results are found.

The code as follows:

```js
var map;
var markers = [];
var side_bar_html = "";
var infoWindow;
var locationSelect;

function load() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
  locationSelect.onchange = function() {
    var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    if (markerNum != "none"){
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
    }
  };
   }

function searchLocations() {
 var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
   } else {
     alert(address + 'Please Enter a Location');
    }
 });
}

function clearLocations() {
 infoWindow.close();
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   markers[i].setMap(null);
 }
 markers.length = 0;
side_bar_html = "";
}

function searchLocationsNear(center) {
 clearLocations(); 

 var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
 var searchUrl = 'xmlmap.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() +  '&radius=' + radius;
 downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
   var xml = parseXml(data);
   var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
     var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
     var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
     var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
     var moreinfo = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("moreinfo");
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

     createOption(name, distance, i);
     createMarker(latlng, name, address, moreinfo);
     bounds.extend(latlng);
   }
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   if (side_bar_html == "") {
   document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = '<strong>No Matches  Found</strong>';}
   else {
   document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;}
  });
}

function createMarker(latlng, name, address, moreinfo) {

  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/>" + moreinfo;
  var cleanaddy = address.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
  html +='<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get"" target="_blank">'+
       '<INPUT value="Get Directions" TYPE="SUBMIT">' +
       '<input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="' + cleanaddy +
       '"/>';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (markers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>'+ address +'<br><br>';
 }
function myclick(i) {
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], "click");
}

function createOption(name, distance, num) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = num;
  option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
  locationSelect.appendChild(option);
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}

function doNothing() {}

//Nothing here>
```

Any hint or idea on how to solve this issue? I spent 3 days already and can't find what the issue is

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try changing `map.fitBounds(bounds);` to `if(!bounds.isEmpty()) {map.fitBounds(bounds);}`. Can you also post a live example?

Comment: Salman, that was exactly it, thank you very much! :)